# Django how to compare auto_now and auto_now_add

Tags: python, django

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I have used this code to stamp the time. And used the following to compare the two and if it is edited I set to express the updated time as shown below.

```
{% if comment.created_at != comment.modified_at %}
    <p class="text-muted float-right"><small>Updated: {{ comment.modified_at }}</small></p>
{% endif %}
```

However, all of the comments say that it has different created_at and modified_at values even though I did not edit thus the two values would be the same. How could I fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`auto_add_now` and `auto_now` usually differ by a few milliseconds, so you have to compare it by a delta, for example:

```
comment.modified_at - comment.created_at < datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
```

A more robust solution, is to store an `edited` flag on the model instead.

Comment: It says TemplateSyntaxError in the html file if I use     {% if comment.modified_at - comment.created_at < datetime.timedelta(seconds=1) %} How should I fix this?

Comment: Calculate it on the view instead of the template.

Comment: difference = comment.modified_at - comment.created_at
                if difference < datetime.timedelta(seconds=1):
                    comment.difference = True
                else:
                    comment.difference = False
Using this causes "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
" this problem. I am so sorry I am kind of new to Django and python so I don't know a lot about it.

Comment: Have you called `comment.save()`? If not, those fields are going to be `None`

Comment: yes, I did but it still has the same problem